# how to add labels of the nodes using sankey_plot command in stata?

Tags: label, stata

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsXLw.png)

I want to label the values at each node. However it does not showing up.
My command is

```
gen x0 = 1
gen x1 = 2
contract x0 x1 A B, freq(freq2)
sankey_plot x0 A x1 B, ///
width0(freq2) /// Adds Width info
extra adjust /// Adjusts coordinates
colorpalette(viridis, opacity(40)) /// adds color options(if installed)
gap(0.1) noline /// adds spaces between nodes, and drops lines in flows
xlabel(1 "A" 2 "B", nogrid)
```

A represents the first node and B represents the second node.

Thank you in advance!

same above. already explained.

Comment: `sankey_plot` is from SSC, as you are asked to explain: see `stata` tag wiki. You'd be more likely to get an answer on Statalist, where the author is a frequent poster.  In any forum a minimal reproducible example can be expected, especially here:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1715627-how-to-add-labels-of-the-nodes-using-sankey_plot-command-in-stata  and a discussion has started. Best to delete this thread, I suggest.